# MSK connectivity issue during AWS Security Patch Updates using Confluent Kafka C# Nuget

Tags: c#, aws-msk, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Facing issues while consuming event from Kafka using AWS MSK during security patch updates.

Program: Basic Consumer application (Regularly consume events infinitely)
Confluent.Kafka nuget version: 2.2.0
Apache Kafka version: 2.8.1
Client configuration: EnableAutoCommit = false; EnableAutoOffsetStore = false;

Logs:

> ssl://b-1.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094/1:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
> [thrd:ssl://b-1.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaw]:
> ssl://b-1.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094/1:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed) 2/2 brokers are
> down
> ssl://b-1.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094/1:
> Disconnected: verify that security.protocol is correctly configured,
> broker might require SASL authentication (after -1616061376ms in state
> UP) GroupCoordinator:
> b-2.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 1ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
> [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator:
> b-2.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 1ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
> ssl://b-2.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094/2:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 1ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
> [thrd:ssl://b-2.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaw]:
> ssl://b-2.devmsk..c17.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9094/2:
> Connect to ipv4#:9094 failed: Connection refused (after
> 1ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)

Reference Issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/2164

Expected: No connectivity error should come during AWS MSK infra updates. Switch to new Leader over different Broker.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide debugging information in the question. The external link is OK but it should be in addition to having all the information in the question. We want questions (and their answers) to be useful even after links break. See [ask].